# How get authentication send to azure function (isolated) send by HttpClient - NetworkCredential?

Tags: azure, function, httpclient

i have some services that run to 'traditional' webapp mvc .net6, they basically create a HttpClient  and send throughht it a NetworkCredential with User and password to another webapp, now i need to replace this second webapp with a azure function, but i don't see how to get the user and password informed to realize some checks, how i do that? i need install some nuget? change something in my function?

in a 'normal' authorization generally i get the jwt token or user and password in the header with i can get easily, but in seans that HttpClient-NetworkCredential send it by another form and/or another place

how to get in the function?:

```
[Function("Function1")]
        public HttpResponseData Run([HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Function, "get", "post")] HttpRequestData req)
        {
```

or in the middleware:?

```
public async Task Invoke(FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
        {
```

i tried look as usual in the'HttpRequestData req' of the function but i cant find it, like it was not send, be in the header or any other place, like azure function did not support this kind of authentication

also tried in the middleware by the var as usual 'FunctionContext context' 'HttpRequestData requestData = await context.GetHttpRequestDataAsync();' also no sucess;

ps. the appservice that is in realease today uses BasicHttpAuthorize

Answer (score 0):

- When you’re running the Azure Functions on the cloud, it is simple process to add the authentication with various [identity providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/overview-authentication-authorization) like *Microsoft, GitHub, Open Id Connect, Facebook, etc.,* as they are provided as built-in features by Microsoft:

[image]

- Using `FunctionContext` Middleware, we can implement the *JWT Access Token* as bearer token authentication format, authorization and also logging feature:

```cs
public  async Task InvokeAuth( FunctionContext context, FunctionExecutionDelegate next)
```

- Function App needs to be registered with the *Azure Active Directory* in order to generate the necessary configuration like **`AuthenticationClientId`**, **`AuthenticationAuthority`**, **`Scope`**, **`AppId`**, etc., for issuing the Authenticating Access token.
- Here is the *Joonasw* [blog](https://joonasw.net/view/azure-ad-jwt-authentication-in-net-isolated-process-azure-functions) that helps you for implementing with C# code for using the authentication of JWT Access Token Issuer and validation in Azure Function App along with the Authorization Validation functionality using the `FunctionContext` Middleware.